# Exporting a environment variable in Entrypoint file not work?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, entry-point, docker-entrypoint

I have some problems with exporting an environment variable into docker Entrypoint file.

This is my docker file content:

```
   FROM ubuntu:16.04
   ADD entrypoint.sh .
   RUN chmod 777 entrypoint.sh
   ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
   CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

In the Entrypoint file, I try to run command "export TOKEN=$client_token". Then, I create a container with that image file and I run "docker exec -it  /bin/bash" command and into the container I continue run "set" command to show all environment variables. So,I can not find the $TOKEN variable that I exported before.

How can I export an environment variable into the entrypoint file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must inject your host environment variable (client_token) into the docker container using '-e' when running:

```
docker run -it --rm -e client_token=<whatever> <your image>
```

This works for example with this kind of entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TOKEN=$client_token
echo "The TOKEN is: ${TOKEN}"
# do stuff ...
```

If you don't know the token value when the container was run, you should inject during attachment (*docker exec*) and perform required operations inside, but probably it is not valid for you if running container already needed that information.

```
docker exec -it -e TOKEN=<whatever> <your container>
```

BRs

Comment: Thanks for your help. So, The detail of my case is I have a entrypoint file contains the script run to get token value and assign it into an environment variable as a token and export it. After I created the container, the token environment variable not exist in my container. Is there have any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, i think i didn't understood actually the question. I will edit my answer. As far i understand, your host environment knows 'client_token' value in the moment of running the container. You have to inject client_token then.

Comment: Thanks for your support @eramos. That problem has been resolved. Again, I want to say thank you.

Comment: Thank u, you are the first person I help in stackoverflow ;) it is a pleasure. Normally i get help from here, everyday! BRs

Comment: Could you update with the solution to this problem?